# Struggling to implement a differential evolutionary algorithm from a paper in python3 with DEAP

Tags: python, evolutionary-algorithm, deap, differential-evolution

I'm trying to implement a differential evolution algorithm to solve for the parameters of a PV model. I think the code I've written is correct, but I seem to be getting weird answers. With each run of the algorithm, I get new parameters, which vary wildly. Furthermore I can't seem to solve the equation using sympy either as I think the exponent produces an enormous value which results in overflow. The following error code is obtained using the sympy solve: "Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t"

```
import random
from random import randint
import array
import math
import numpy
from deap import base
from deap import tools
from deap import benchmarks
from deap import creator
from decimal import Decimal
import sympy
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import Eq

# STEP 1 -> Defined constants
## number of individuals in the population
NP = 300
##coefficients from the datasheet of the PV panel
IscTempcoeff = 0.059
VocTempcoeff = -0.32
PeakPowTempcoeff = - 0.43
Voc = 45.79
Vmp = 36.38
Isc = 8.99
Imp = 8.52
Vt = 0.026
##amount of generations
max = 300
##lower and upper bounds of the variables to solve
Xih = [2, 1, 3000, 0.1, Isc]
Xil = [1, 0.1, 100, 0.000009, 0.1]


#crossover based on binomial
def cxBinomial(x, mutant, cr):
   size = len(x)
   index = random.randrange(size)
    for i in range(size):
        if i == index or random.random() < cr:
            x[i] = mutant[i]
    return x

#mutation function
def mutateDE(mutant, a, b, c, f):
    size = len(mutant)
    for i in range(len(mutant)):
        mutant[i] = a[i] + f * (b[i] - c[i])
    return mutant

#Penalty function to ensure the parameters remain in acceptable range
def cxPenalty(x):
    z = random.uniform(0, 1)
    if (x[0] > 2 or x[1] > 1 or x[2] > 3000 or x[3] > 0.1 or x[4] > Isc):
        x[0] = x[0] - (z * (Xih[0] - Xil[0]))
        x[1] = x[1] - (z * (Xih[1] - Xil[1]))
        x[2] = x[2] - (z * (Xih[2] - Xil[2]))
        x[3] = x[3] - (z * (Xih[3] - Xil[3]))
        x[4] = x[4] - (z * (Xih[4] - Xil[4]))
     elif (x[0] < Xil[0] or x[1] < Xil[1] or x[2] < Xil[2] or x[3] < Xil[3] or x[4] < Xil[4]):
        x[0] = x[0] + (z * (Xih[0] - Xil[0]))
        x[1] = x[1] + (z * (Xih[1] - Xil[1]))
        x[2] = x[2] + (z * (Xih[2] - Xil[2]))
        x[3] = x[3] + (z * (Xih[3] - Xil[3]))
        x[4] = x[4] + (z * (Xih[4] - Xil[4]))

     return x

 #evaluation and selection function
def eval(a, Rs, Rp, Io):
    r = (1 / (a * Vt))
    Gp = (1 / Rp)
    preex = Decimal(r*(Vmp + (Imp * Rs)))
    expo = numpy.exp(preex)
    Jnum = Decimal(Io) * Decimal(r) * expo - Decimal(Gp)
    Jden = 1 + (Decimal(Io) * Decimal(r) * Decimal(Rs) * expo) + Decimal(Gp * Rs)
    J = Jnum / Jden
    return J


def main():
    generation = 0
    state = []
    creator.create("Fitnessmin", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0,))
    creator.create("Individual", array.array, typecode='d', fitness=creator.Fitnessmin)
    toolbox = base.Toolbox()
    toolbox.register("attr_a", random.uniform, 1, 2)
    toolbox.register("attr_rs", random.uniform, 0.1, 1)
    toolbox.register("attr_rp", random.uniform, 100, 3000)
    toolbox.register("attr_io", random.uniform, 0.000009, 0.1)
    toolbox.register("attr_ipv", random.uniform, 0.1, Isc)
    toolbox.register("individual", tools.initCycle, creator.Individual,
                 (toolbox.attr_a, toolbox.attr_rs, toolbox.attr_rp,     toolbox.attr_io, toolbox.attr_ipv), 1)
    toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
    toolbox.register("mutate", mutateDE, f=0.4)
    toolbox.register("select", tools.selRandom, k=3)
    toolbox.register("mate", cxBinomial, cr=0.4)
    toolbox.register("evaluate", eval)
    # STEP 2 - > generate population
    pop1 = toolbox.population(n=NP)
    # STEP 3 -> start the algorithm
    ## Hall of fame to save the best individual
    hof = tools.HallOfFame(1)
    while (generation <= max):
        for agent in pop1:
            # Mutation
            a, b, c = [toolbox.clone(ind) for ind in     toolbox.select(pop1)]
            mutant1 = toolbox.clone(agent)
            mutant = toolbox.clone(agent)
            mutant = toolbox.mutate(mutant, a, b, c)
            # crossover
            trialvec = toolbox.mate(mutant1, mutant)
            trialvec = cxPenalty(trialvec)
            trialeval = toolbox.evaluate(trialvec[0], trialvec[1], trialvec[2], trialvec[3])
            curreval = toolbox.evaluate(agent[0], agent[1], agent[2], agent[3])

            if (trialeval < curreval):
                #selection -> trialvector is better than original vector
                agent = trialvec
                state.append(trialeval)
            else:
                 #selection -> trialvector IS NOT better than original vector
                state.append(curreval)

        hof.update(pop1)
        print(generation)
        generation = generation + 1

    ##extract best individual from the hall of fame
    bestid = hof[0]
    ##extract parameters from individual
    a = round((bestid[0]), 2)
    Rs = round((bestid[1]), 2)
    Rp = round((bestid[2]), 2)
    print("Io")
    io = round((bestid[3]), 2)
    print(io)
    print("RS")
    print(Rs)
    print("Rp")
    print(Rp)
    print("a")
    print(a)
    I = Symbol('I')
    r = (1 / (a * Vt))
    #Solve to ensure that Imp is retrieved when Vmp is provided
    print("solving start")
    ## solving equation 3
    eqn = Eq(Isc-io*(((sympy.exp(r*(Vmp + (I * Rs))))) - 1)-((Vmp+(I*Rs))/Rp ) - I)
    t = solve(eqn,I,rational=False,real=True)
    print("solving done")
    print(t)


main()
```

I'm expecting to receive somewhat similar parameters each time I run the algorithm, so I assume I made a mistake somewhere and I really can't find it, thus I need some help as I'm still getting a grip on python and evolutionary algorithms.

[This](https://docdro.id/M4l3Yh7) is the paper.

They provide an explanation of each step on page 3 and show the pseudo-code on page 5.

Any and all help will really be appreciated as I'm not sure what's wrong nor do I know of someone that could help. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: What makes you think you should be getting the same parameters at each run?